# Google sites : Email notifications when site is published

Tags: google-sites, google-sites-2016

As an owner of google sites, I never receive an email notification when I update/publish site changes. Is there any setting for this?

This would be useful particularly to ensure that the site hasn't been hacked and changes published by anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't any feature where Google Sites can send email notifications whenever changes are being published by a different user.

But, there is a [Version History](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9622187) feature wherein it logs all changes made on your website as well as the user who made those changes.